# How to write and read in a different encoding from the terminal?

Tags: character-encoding

I'm using terminator on debian, and its enconding is set to UTF-8. In most cases this isn't a problem since almost everything that's recent has the encoding set to utf-8 aswell.

When I connect to a specific mysql database that has a different encoding and preform a select the result comes out with some � characaters. When updating tables, the results on the other end also are messed up.

Is there any way to connect to the database (or set the shell) so I can see and write in a different encoding? (latin1 in this case)

Comment: You said write, but then whet on to describe reading. Which is it?

Comment: fixed the title

Comment: [`luit`](https://invisible-island.net/luit/luit.html) is used for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using this command:

```
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8 LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 gnome-terminal
```

to create a UTF-8 based window from an environment that is using the mille European default ISO-8859-1

You could  do something similar but replace `de_DE.UTF-8` with what you need.